# ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword error. What should I do?

Tags: oracle

```
insert into Members
  (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,DOB,GENDER,MOBILE,EMERGENCY_NAME,
  EMERGENCY_PHONE,EMAIL,MEDICAL_HISTORY,ADDRESS,START_DATE,
  PLAN,ID)
,values('n1','n2','02.05.1998','M','5456764645','h',
'566576876','fhsfsdfo','none','bla','29.10.2015',
8,1);

FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,GENDER,MOBILE,EMERGENCY_NAME,EMERGENCY_PHONE,
EMAIL,MEDICAL_HISTORY,ADDRESS are varchar(30)-s

ID is int and the primary key

DOB and START_DATE are DATE-s

PLAN is int.
```

I get the following error:

> ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a comma (`,`) in your query before `VALUES`. Remove it:

```
insert into Members(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,DOB,GENDER,MOBILE,EMERGENCY_NAME,EMERGENCY_PHONE,EMAIL,MEDICAL_HISTORY,ADDRESS,START_DATE,PLAN,ID) 
values('n1','n2','02.05.1998','M','5456764645','h','566576876','fhsfsdfo','none','bla','29.10.2015',8,1);
```

Comment: @Marian: if this answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking on the little checkmark underneath the vote count next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for Oracle Insert is as below.

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('value1','value2','value3');
```

So your code goes this way

```
insert into Members(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,DOB,GENDER,MOBILE,EMERGENCY_NAME,EMERGENCY_PHONE,EMAIL,MEDICAL_HISTORY,ADDRESS,START_DATE,PLAN,ID) values('n1','n2','02.05.1998','M','5456764645','h','566576876','fhsfsdfo','none','bla','29.10.2015',8,1);
```

The comma before value has to be removed.